# Problem using the Fourier transform and convolution to compute an integral

Tags: calculus, algorithms, numerical-methods, fourier-analysis

I'm trying to write a subroutine (in Fortran) to compute integrals of the form $$I=\int_{-L}^{L} f(x)g(y-x) \:\mathrm{d}x, $$
using the convolution theorem and fast Fourier transforms. In my routine, I have discretized $f$ and $g$ uniformly on a domain $(-L,L]$. I then try to compute the integral via $$ I = \mathrm{ifft}(\:\mathrm{fft}(f(x))\cdot\mathrm{fft}(g(x))). $$ However, I cannot get my routine to give me the correct results. As a test, I try to compute $$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\mathrm{sin}(x)\mathrm{cos}(y-x)\:\mathrm{d}x, $$ which I believe should give me $\pi\; \mathrm{sin}(y)$. I discretize $x$ into $n$ points. Following the advice of some textbooks, I extend the arrays which contain my discretized functions, and pad them with zeros, so that the sin$(x)$ "signal" looks like: [image: sin$(x)$]

and the cos$(x)$ "signal" looks like: [image]

where the function has also been "wrapped around" as well as zero padded. These two signals are then multiplied together, then multiplied by the grid spacing, $2\pi/n$, and then inverse transformed. The result, (which should be the convolution) looks like this: [image]

My textbook tells me that part of the result is garbage, which should be discarded, leaving me with the convolution. Looking at the plot above, it looks like I should discard the last half of the signal. The first half of the signal resembles the $\pi$sin$(x)$ that I'm looking for, but it is not scaled correctly. How can I get the correct convolution? I've been stuck on this for some days now and would really appreciate any comments or tips. Thanks.

## Edit : Update

I am now trying without the zeropadding. However I am still using "wrap-around" format for the second function. That is, the first half of the array contains the function at positive $x$, and the second half of the array contains the function at negative $x$. The result I get is a sin wave, but still not scaled correctly. In fact here is a plot of the error of my routine for different $n$: [image]

Clearly its crap.

## Edit 2

By extending the arrays to include multiple periods of the signals - as suggested by @copper.hat - instead of zero padding, I am getting good results. My routine now accurately approximates the integral, giving me accuracy to within machine precision as desired : [image]

Comment: Why are you padding with zeros? The function should be extended to be periodic.

Comment: I'm just following the advice of [Numerical Recipes in Fortran](http://apps.nrbook.com/fortran/index.html) and also [this site](http://www.music.miami.edu/programs/mue/Research/jvandekieft/jvchapter2.htm). Apparently the zero padding helps to protect the signal from wrap around effects, and is also needed because the FFT method actualy computes the circular convolution, not the linear convolution.

Comment: Why are zeropadding in the middle of the $\cos$ function? Just zeropad on the end of the signals so that each is at least $M+N-1$ samples long, where $M$ and $N$ are the lengths of the input vectors.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you want. The integral you have computed above is correct, however, the function $y \mapsto I(y)$ does not have a Fourier transform in the usual sense. To use the DFT to approximate the integral, you need the function to drop off rapidly at some point.

Comment: So does that mean I cannot use this method to compute the convolution of sin with cos?

Comment: After thinking about it some more, I think you need to both extend the functions to cover a couple periods and then zeropad. I think you're seeing the result of convolving not $\sin(x)$ but $\sin(x) \cdot \operatorname{rect}(x/T)$. I still don't understand why you zeropadding in the middle of the $\cos$, but if you're convinced it's correct, then go for it. Lastly, after the inverse DFT, you'll want to subset the data corresponding to the interval of interest.

Comment: Well, you are trying to compute the Fourier transform of a function that is periodic and so the transform needs to be interpreted in a distribution sense (or as a Fourier series).  To use the above as an approximation, you need to deal with functions which have transforms in the usual sense. One way is to cut them off using $\operatorname{rect}$ as @AnonSubmitter85 alluded to. This is an important point.

Comment: Forgive me, I don't quite understand the point about rect. Are we saying that I should represent sin and cos on a domain greater than $(-\pi,\pi]$ so that I can capture more than one period? And then extend it even further with zeropadding? I might add that the reason I'm working on this problem in the first place is because I'm working on a neural field model, which involves solving integro-differential equations - the kernels of which are convolutions and should be solved using this fft method.

Comment: I think @copper.hat 's point is that your functions go on forever without tending to zero, so that they do not have an FT is the usual sense. You need to limit their support in order to calculate their transform. This can be done by multiplying by a rect function.

Comment: I am still not sure what you are trying to achieve, so my comments should be interpreted in that light. Are $f,g$ periodic with period $2L$? Or are they integrable on the real line?

Comment: Yes, I'm only dealing with periodic functions.

Comment: I think I see what you are doing. You are taking the $2L$ periodic convolution, I presume. In this case, you are using the DFT to approximate the Fourier series. In the particular example you have above, the DFT should be exact (except for possible scaling), however, you should not zero extend, you should extend periodically, and take the number of points to be 4 or more for sampling reasons. For more complex $f,g$ you need to take a sufficient number of samples to capture most of the 'bandwidth'.

Comment: Thank you very much @copper.hat. By extending periodically as you suggested, my routine is giving good results. I have included a second edit in my post above to include a plot showing the accuracy :)

Comment: @OSmith: Excellent!